# How to paint image into MS Word document using DocumentFormat.OpenXML if I have a Base64 encoded string?

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a Base64 encoded string and I wish to convert it to image and paint it in word document using DocumentFormat.openXML

Comment: What is a 64-bit encoded string? Do you mean base64?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have corrected the question . Yes, I mean base64

Answer (score 0):

as regular binary images.
for get bytes use `Convert.FromBase64String(theBase64string)`, and for stream use `MemoryStream`:

```
using(var m = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(theBase64string)))
{
    //here, same code to insert regular binary images
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please help with the code to insert a regular image. I am new to this.